# when click on editText show the android keyboard

Tags: android

How to show and hide keyboard in android.For example when i click on the editText keyboard should display and when i click outside of edittext keyboard should get hidden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just try it..

```
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

for hide keyboard

```
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

for show keyboard

```
     imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
```

where ed is EditText..

Answer (score 5):

I've been using **showSoftInput** for a while but I've also found this alternative 
which simulates click on the EditText by using **dispatchTouchEvent**:

```
            ed.requestFocus();
            ed.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
            ed.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));
```

Didn't notice any difference though...