# prevent EditText to show SoftKeyboard when focused

Tags: android, keyboard, popup

Well, this is dragging me crazy...
I've already read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496901/android-on-screen-keyboard-auto-popping-up), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892615/how-to-remove-auto-focus-keyboard-popup-of-a-field-when-the-screen-shows-up) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495750/when-click-on-edittext-show-the-android-keyboard), but nothing works for me.

**SCENARIO**
This is the scenario: my polls application reads the survey from a configuration file, the questions may have single, multiple or text answers.
In the first case i add RadioButtons to the activity, in the second case Checkboxes and in the third case some multiline EditText.

All works fine, but when the survey is scrolled down the focus is *automatically received* by the next EditText that *automatically shows* the SoftKeyboard.
This is very annoing considering that my user may want to respond to first question, then to the second and then jump to the last only to return to the third one in a second time.

Currently at the very first time the first EditText receives the focus, the keyboard popups and still remains even if the user continue scrolling down (and so even when the cursed EditText finally lost the focus).

**QUESTION**
How can i have an EditText that shows the keyboard *ONLY WHEN IT IS CLICKED* by the user and *NOT* when receives only the focus?

**ENVIRO**
Level 13 APIs (Honeycomb)

Thanks in advance
Lorenzo (that is seriously considering open a resturant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your onCreate(..) method you  can set your EditText control to be unfocusable using

```
EditText.setFocusable(false);
```

This should prevent the keyboard from display on scrolling.
In your onClickListener(..) you can reenable it using

```
EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
EditText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the property

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

at your scrollView container

Comment: Thank you for your answer Felipe. Unfortunately it doesn't work: scrolling down the ScrollView container the first EditText is still receiving the focus and the keyboard continues to pop up. Maybe subclassing EditText?

Comment: Wait, something is appening: adding the android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" not to the outer ScrollView but to the inner vertical LinearLayout the keyboard doesn't appear (but seems that EditTextes do not receive the focus at all). Perhaps this is a good starting point...